# DDD and Client/Server apps

Tags: apache-flex, silverlight, domain-driven-design, client-server

I was wondering if any of you had successfully implemented DDD in a Client/Server app and would like to share some experiences.

We are currently working on a smart client in Flex and a backend in Java. On the server we have a service layer exposed to the client that offers CRUD operations amongst some other service methods. I understand that in DDD these services should be repositories and services should be used to handle use cases that do not fit inside a repository. Right now, we mimic these services on the client behind an interface and inject implementations (Webservices, RMI, etc) via an IoC container.

So some questions arise:

- should the server expose repositories to the client or do we need to have some sort of a facade (that is able to handle security for instance)
- should the client implement repositories (and DDD in general?) knowing that in the client, most of the logic is view related and real business logic lives on the server. All communication with the server happens asynchronously and we have a single threaded programming model on the client.
- how about mapping client to server objects and vice versa? We tried DTO's but reverted back to exposing the state of our objects and mapping directly to them. I know this is considered bad practice, but it saves us an incredible amount of time)

In general I think a new generation of applications is coming with the growth of Flex, Silverlight, JavaFX and I'm curious how DDD fits into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would not expose repositories directly to the client. The first big problem as you mention is security: you can't trust the client, so you cannot expose your data access API to potentially hostile clients.
2. Wrap your repositories with services on the server and create a thin delegate layer in the client that handles the remote communication.
3. Exposing your Entities is not necessarily a bad practice it's just that it becomes problematic when you start to factor in things like lazy loading, sending data over the wire the client doesn't need, etc. If you write a DTO class which wraps one or more entities and delegates get/set calls you can actually build up a DTO layer pretty quickly, especially using code generation available in most IDEs.

The key to all of this is that a set of patterns should really only apply to a part of your application, not to the whole thing. The fact that you have rich logic in your domain model and use repositories for data access as part of DDD should not influence the client in any way. Conceptually the RIAs that I build have three layers:

1. Client uses something like MVC, MVP or MVVM to present the UI. The Model layer eventually calls into...
2. What I might call the "Integration Layer." This is a contract of services and data objects that exist on both the client and server to allow the two to coordinate. Usually the UI design drives this layer so that (A) only the data that the client needs is passed to it and (B) data access can be coarse-grained, i.e. "make one method call for all the state needed for this set of UI.
3. Server using whatever it wants to handle business logic and data access. This might be DDD or something a little more old school, like a data layer built using stored procs in the DB and a lot of "ResultSet" or "DataTable" objects.

The point really is that the client and server are both very different animals and they need to vary independently. In order to do so, you need a layer inbetween that is a fair compromise between the needs of the UI and the reality of how things might need to be on the server.

The one big advantage that Silverlight/WPF and JavaFX have over Flex + anything is that you can use a lot of logic in the first two because you have the same VM on both sides of the app. Flex is the best UI technology hands down but it lacks a server component where code could be shared and re-used more effectively.